# VPN на Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012

У меня несколько вопросов:

1. Мне нужен скоростной VPN для дома, чтобы скорость интернета не особо падала. Какой лучше выбрать?
2. Я настроил l2tp vpn с NATом, но скорость падает более, чем в 2 раза, когда тестирую сеть на пропускную способность. Пробовал убирать шифрование, но не помогло. С PPTP тоже самое. Хочу протестировать IKEv2 на скорость.
3. Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить vpn с IKEv2 на windows server 2012? На сервере нет домена и нет Active Directory. Можно ли где настроить по инструкции (я не нашел нормальной)?